# While creating a 1D list of multiple 2D arrays, the first array appended to the list makes it three dimensional. Why?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, append, train-test-split

I have a list of multiple pandas dataframes that I want to use to create a training set and a testing set. For this, I have defined a train_test_split function that splits the dataset and am now trying to create a function that defines the testX and testy datasets from this split.

```
def train_test_split(dataset, n_test): #n_test is the number of testing sets needed
    trainset = []
    testset = []
    for i in range(0, len(dataset)-n_test):
        trainset.append(dataset[i])
    for i in range (len(dataset)-n_test, len(dataset)):
        testset.append(dataset[i])
    return trainset, testset
```

Within this list of datasets, each dataset has 48 columns all with the same names but with varying number of rows. For each dataset, after accounting for python's 0 indexing, X was obtained from the following column numbers: 1,2,3,7,8,9,13,14,15... etc while y came from columns 4,5,10,11,16,17... etc. To define testX and testY I created a function that copied X and Y correctly from each dataframe.

```
def skip_a_b_c(num_cols,a,b,c): #starting from a, skip b numbers every c numbers
    dataset = []
    for i in range(a,num_cols,b+c):
        for j in range(i,c+i):
            dataset.append(j)
    return dataset
```

For p and q defined in the main function below, p = [1,2,3,7,8,9,13,14,15.....45] and q = [4,5,10,11...47]

When I run the code below, the first iteration results in testX having the shape (1,24,96) when every other run (R) gives the shape as (R,24) which is what is expected. Similarly, the first iteration results in testy having the shape (1,16,96) while every other iteration has the shape (R,16). Why is that just the first run gives a 3D shape?

```
#Main Function:
    def create_testxy(dataset,n_test):
        train,test= train_test_split(dataset, n_test) #train_test_split has been defined
        p = skip_a_b_c(48,1,3,3)
        q = skip_a_b_c(48,4,4,2)
        testX = []
        testy = []
        for testset in test:
            temp_a = list()
            temp_b = list()
            for a in p:
                temp_a.append(testset.iloc[:,a])
            for b in q:
                temp_b.append(testset.iloc[:,b])
            testX.append(temp_a)
            testy.append(temp_b)
        
            print('TEST X SHAPE IS',np.shape(testX))
            print('TESTY SHAPE IS', np.shape(testy))
        return (train, testX, testy)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure about why the above did not work, but I created an alternate function where instead of appending the columns I want, I drop the columns that I don't want.

```
def create_testxy(dataset,n_test):
    train,test = train_test_split(dataset, n_test)
    example = dataset[1]
    num_cols = example.shape[1]
    p = skip_a_b_c(num_cols,1,3,3)
    q = skip_a_b_c(num_cols,4,4,2)
    n = []
    m = []
    for a in range(0,num_cols):
        if a not in p:
            n.append(a)
    for b in range(0,num_cols):
        if b not in q:
            m.append(b)
    testX = []
    testy = []
    history = train.copy()
    for testset in test:
        copy1 = testset.copy()
        copy2 = testset.copy()
        copy1.drop(copy1.columns[n], axis=1, inplace=True)
        copy2.drop(copy2.columns[m], axis=1, inplace=True)
        testX.append(copy1)
        testy.append(copy2)
    print('\n TEST X SHAPE IS',np.shape(testX))
    print('\n TESTY SHAPE IS', np.shape(testy))
    print('\n Shape of one Dataframe inside testx is ', np.shape(testX[2]))
        
    return (train, history, testX, testy)
```